# Getting the download progress Google Drive

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

Is there a way to get callbacks on the didReceiveData of NSURLConnection or another way to track the download progress when downloading a Google Drive file?

I only see an uploadProgress one and the download method takes a completion block.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a code snippet for you:

```
self.fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
[self.fetcher setReceivedDataBlock:^(NSData *data) {
    float percentTransfered = self.fetcher.downloadedLength * 100.0f / self.fetcher.response.expectedContentLength;
    // Do something with progress
}
```

expectedContentLength will return -1 if the size of the downloaded file is unknown.